# How to set default parse_mode in node-telegram-bot-api

Tags: node.js, node-telegram-bot-api

`bot.sendMessage(chatId,"hi",{parse_mode:"Markdown"})`
I use this method , But I always want the same parsing mode, is there any way to do that ??